# React Add key in component

Tags: reactjs, key

I getting this error:

**index.js:2178 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.**

It's my object:

```
class NumberColumn extends Component {
  _getNumbers() {
    let numbers = []
    let i = 0

    while (i < 10) {
      numbers.push(<div>{i}</div>)
      i++
    }

    return numbers
  }

  render() {
    const { current } = this.props

    return (
      <div className="vote__column">
        <Motion
          style={{y: spring(current * 10)}}
        >
          {({y}, i) =>
            <div
              key ={i}
              style={{
                transform: `translateY(${-y}%)`
              }}
            >
              {this._getNumbers()}  
            </div>
          }
        </Motion>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Where should i assigne key prop?

Comment: What does you `this._getNumbers` function return?

Comment: It's returns number in Vote :)

Comment: Could you include the entire component in your question?

Comment: Check these other answers as well, they really have a good explanation about the key, [**link**](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Each+child+in+an+array+or+iterator+should+have+a+unique+%22key%22+prop+site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN785IN785&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwil0syIysfcAhUMYo8KHY1UC4YQrQIoBDAAegQIAhAM&biw=1440&bih=803)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element in an array used for rendering [should have a `key` prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

You can use the index of each element as `key` in the array you return from `_getNumbers`.

**Example**

```
_getNumbers() {
  let numbers = []
  let i = 0

  while (i < 10) {
    numbers.push(<div key={i}>{i}</div>)
    i++
  }

  return numbers
}
```

Comment: Where should i add key in this example. Please only advice i need to learn how to do it correctly :)

const Result = ({ state: { products, displayCategory} }) =>
<div>
  {products
    .filter(({ category }) =>
        displayCategory === category || displayCategory === "all"
    )
    .map(({ category, name, StartDate, EndDate, BtcGoal, BtcDonated, desc, img}) =>
      <ResultItem category={category} name={name} desc={desc} StartDate ={StartDate} EndDate ={EndDate} BtcGoal={BtcGoal} BtcDonated={BtcDonated} img ={img}/>
    )}
</div>;

Comment: @PiotrŻak Please read the piece of documentation I linked in the answer. Every element in an array used for rendering should have a unique key, so `ResultItem` in that case should have a key.

Comment: I trying make it in this form:

    .map(({index, category, name, StartDate, EndDate, BtcGoal, BtcDonated, desc, img}) =>
      <ResultItem key ={index} category={category} name={name} desc={desc} StartDate ={StartDate} EndDate ={EndDate} BtcGoal={BtcGoal} BtcDonated={BtcDonated} img ={img}/>
    )}

But it's still erroring

Answer (score -1):

Each `div` should have it's own unique `key`:

```
<Motion
  style={{y: spring(current * 10)}}
>
  {({y}, i) =>
    <div
      key={i}
      style={{
        transform: `translateY(${-y}%)`
      }}
    >
      {this._getNumbers()}
    </div>
  }
</Motion>
```